# node.js server can't get data from mongoDB atlas after running long time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Server running under nginx and pm2.
It user mongoose to connect to MongoDB Atlas.
Frontend use axios to fetch data from server.

After server running a long time (several days), my website can't get data from MongoDB Atlas. It showed 500 server error.

The server is still running, show UI, but can't get data. After I restart the whole server, then it worked fine.

Who had met this kind of situation?

Server

```
const express = require('express')
const connectDB = require('./config/db.js')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

// Connect Database
connectDB()

// Init middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

// Define routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'))
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'))
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'))

// Serve the static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

Connect mongoDB

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const config = require('config')
const db = config.get('mongoURI')

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
    })

    console.log('MongoDB connected...')
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    // Exit process with failure
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Comment: where do you actually access the database? i only see the initial connection and then everything about it seems to just be discarded

Comment: I put in server.js file, `connectDB()` on the top of `app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))`

Comment: that connects to the database but does not query it for anything...